# Deserialize JSON array based on nested type attribute

Tags: swift, codable

Consider this example JSON:

```
{
    "sections": [{
        "title": "Sign up",
        "rows": [
            {
                "type": "image",
                "imageURL": "https://example.com/image.jpg"
            },
            {
                "type": "textField",
                "value": "",
                "placeholder": "Username"
            },
            {
                "type": "textField",
                "placeholder": "password"
            },
            {
                "type": "textField",
                "placeholder": "confirmPassword"
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "placeholder": "Register!"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Let's say I wanted to parse the JSON above into the following models *(I know it doesn't compile due to the `Row` protocol not corresponding to `Decodable`)*:

```
enum RowType: String, Codable {
    case textField
    case image
    case button
}

protocol Row: Codable {
    var type: RowType { get }
}

struct TextFieldRow: Row {
    let type: RowType
    let placeholder: String
    let value: String

    enum CodingKey: String {
        case type
        case placeholder
        case value
    }
}

struct ImageRow: Row {
    let type: RowType
    let imageURL: URL

    enum CodingKey: String {
        case type
        case imageURL
    }
}

struct ButtonRow: Row {
    let type: RowType
    let title: String

    enum CodingKey: String {
        case type
        case title
    }
}

struct Section: Codable {
    let rows: [Row]
    let title: String

    enum CodingKey: String {
        case rows
        case title
    }
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let sections: [Section]

    enum CodingKey: String {
        case sections
    }
}


// Parsing the response using the Foundation JSONDecoder
let data: Data // From network
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
```

Is there a way to make the Swift code above Codable compliant? 
I know you can manually solve this by first grabbing each `Row`'s `type` string and then creating the right type of `Row` model as well as changing them from structs to classes and letting the `Row` protocol be a superclass instead. But is there a way that requires less manual labour?

Comment: You can't use `protocol` in place of a concrete type required by `Codable`. You should create a wrapper type that has `type: RowType` and `value: Row`. As you mentioned, based on the type, initialize value row.

Comment: Also, `value` inside `TextFieldRow ` and `title` inside `ButtonRow ` should be `Optional` as per your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `enum` with associated value is the best option:

Consider this enum:

```
enum Row: Decodable {
    case textField(TextFieldRow)
    case image(ImageRow)
    // and other cases

    case unknown

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let selfContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let typeContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            let type = try typeContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)

            switch type {
            case "textField": self = .textField( try selfContainer.decode(TextFieldRow.self) )
            case "Image": self = .image( try selfContainer.decode(ImageRow.self) )
            // and other cases
            default: self = .unknown
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these changes:

```
struct TextFieldRow: Decodable {
    let placeholder: String?
    let value: String?
}

struct ImageRow: Decodable {
    let imageURL: URL
}

// and so on
```

Now this will decode like a charm:

```
// Minmal testing JSON
let json = """
[
            {
                "type": "image",
                "imageURL": "https://example.com/image.jpg"
            },
            {
                "type": "textField",
                "value": "",
                "placeholder": "Username"
            },
            {
                "type": "textField",
                "placeholder": "password"
            }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
print( try! decoder.decode([Row].self, from: json) )
```

You can now add any other case you need to the decoder to build your *application builder* app.

Comment: Great suggestion, I've marked it as the answer. Thank you!